# "list indices must be integers, not list" with enumerate

Tags: python

I have this code

```
cNames = data["channelnames"]
goodChannels = [i for i,x in enumerate(cNames) if x!='Skipped']
data["channelnames"]=cNames[goodChannels]
```

I need the channel numbers later, but the cNames[goodChannels] throws the error "list indices must be integers, not list"

the list is made of integers.  Is there a way to make this work correctly?

cNames[np.array(goodChannels)] does not work with the same error, so I am assuming that there is something else going on here.

Comment: What do you think that `cNames[goodChannels]` does? What index number is a list?

Comment: You cannot index a list with another list of integers. It must either be a slice, or a single integer.

Comment: Matlab translation mistake.  I can see the problem now. Thank you

Comment: @ochensati you can do that with numpy arrays and pandas data structures but not with vanilla python lists. In general, though, it is better to work with boolean masks instead of index arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another list comprehension:

```
data["channelnames"] = [cNames[i] for i in goodChannels]
```

Comment: Or better yet, skip the middleman and simply `data['channelnames'] = [name for name in data['channelnames'] if name != 'skipped']`